# Pause while loop with keyboard input

Tags: c, while-loop

Is there any way that i can pause my infinite while loop whenever i press e or w or any key of my choice and let the user enter the value and resume the loop again?

```
 while(1){
//some code
//i want to pause this loop whenver i want with a key and resume again
}
```

Comment: i want to pause whenever i want, change some valus and then continue

Comment: I think you are looking for something like a synchronization primitive (locks/ semaphores) etc. 
The I/O thread can acquire a lock which in turn disables the loop to execute and the loop will have to wait on the lock to get freed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on console you using.

If you are using windows shell, I would write something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

void checkKey() {
    int key;
    if (_kbhit()) {
        key =_getch();
        if (key == 'w' || key == 'e') {
            getch();
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("loop is doing something");
    while(1) {
        printf(".");
        Sleep(100);
        checkKey();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

_kbhit() check if some key was pressed then getch() "pause" program until any key is pressed.

That code would be completely different for unix terminal implementation. In that case you should read about termio and non-blocking mode (pretty difficult stuff).

If you're writing some kind of graphic app then you have to check key handling documentation of libraries that you're using. For example functionality of glutKeyboardFunc() for OpenGL "GLUT" library.

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask if you don't understand something.

Comment: its not allowing me to pause again after i enter the value

Comment: void checkKey() {
    int key;
    if (_kbhit()) {
        key =_getch();
  switch(key){
  case 'e':scanf("%.2f",&harvest);
      break;
  case 'w':scanf("%.2f",&harvest);
      break;
  case 'p':scanf("%7d",&maxPopu);
    break;
  case 'o':scanf("%7d",&maxPopu);
    break;
  case 'k':scanf("%f",&growth);
    break;
  case 'l':scanf("%f",&growth);
    break;
  case 'q': exit(0);
  }
       
        }
    }